# mathabx integral sign in newtxmath style

Tags: fonts, symbols

I discovered that the Libertine font can be implemented in math mode using the `newtxmath` package. However, I prefer the integral sign from the `mathabx` package rather than the one contained in `newtxmath`. Is there any way to substitute only this one symbol? I'm using pdfLaTeX from TeX Live Manager on Windows 10.

P.S.: I'm not too much into the mechanics of TeX... so please try to keep your answer as simple as possible!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy some of the declarations from `mathabx`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{<->mathx10}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\intop}  {\mathop}{mathx}{"B3}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\iintop} {\mathop}{mathx}{"B4}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\iiintop}{\mathop}{mathx}{"B5}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\ointop} {\mathop}{mathx}{"B6}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\oiintop}{\mathop}{mathx}{"B7}


\begin{document}

This is almost trivial to prove:
\begin{equation*}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^{2}}\,dx=\sqrt{\pi}
\end{equation*}
And here are the other integral symbols:
\begin{equation*}
\int\quad\iint\quad\iiint\quad\oint\quad\oiint
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You may also want to try `esint`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{esint}

\begin{document}

This is almost trivial to prove:
\begin{equation*}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^{2}}\,dx=\sqrt{\pi}
\end{equation*}
And here are the other integral symbols:
\begin{equation*}
\int\quad\iint\quad\iiint\quad\oint\quad\oiint
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A third possibility is to use the `cmintegrals` option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[libertine,cmintegrals]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

This is almost trivial to prove:
\begin{equation*}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^{2}}\,dx=\sqrt{\pi}
\end{equation*}
And here are the other integral symbols:
\begin{equation*}
\int\quad\iint\quad\iiint\quad\oint
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]