# cmintegrals options for newtxmath not working

Tags: math-mode, newtxmath, integral

So I was recently looking for free alternatives to `mtpro2` and `newtx` caught my attention. I decided to run `newtxmath` package with the Computer Modern integrals via the option `cmintegrals`, but unfortunately running through both MikTeX and Overleaf (pdfLaTeX) the following

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[cmintegrals]{newtxmath}

\[ \oint \mathbf{E} \cdot d \mathbf{a} = \int \rho \, dv \]
```

results in

[image: 1]

which are the same integral signs as compiling without `cmintegrals`. Does someone know what could be causing this strange behavior and how could I fix it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. From p. 6 of the manual of the newtx package: "[A]s of version 1.5, [the `cmintegrals`] option does nothing, as the new default is slanted integral." Put differently, you're getting the Computer Modern-type slanted integral symbols whether or not you specify the option `cmintegrals`. (I believe the most recent version of the `newtxmath` package has version number. 1.553.)

Comment: @Mico thanks for your clarification! I found a workaround by loading `esint` after `newtxmath`. I still wish there was support for `cmintegrals` like in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/289363/mathabx-integral-sign-in-newtxmath-style).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the question is solved of the OP migrating on other packages.