# Borrowing the integral and summation signs from mathabx package

Tags: mathabx

I am trying to use *only* the integral and summation symbols from mathabx package.

[mathabx integral sign in newtxmath style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/289363/mathabx-integral-sign-in-newtxmath-style)

In this question, someone provided codes for adding the integral signes, so I tried to tweak it to add the summation sign (\sum), but failed...

Could you please help me on this one?

In general, if I have a particular sybol that I would like to borrow from come package, and I want to use *only* that, how can I accomplish it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The `\sum` symbol as well as the other math symbols of `mathabx` are defined in `mathabx.dcl` file. In particular, the font family of`\sum` is `mathx`, the same family of the symbols defined in the post you mentioned. So you just need to add these two lines to the solution of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/289379/231952.

```
\let\sum\relax
\DeclareMathSymbol{\sum}{\mathop}{mathx}{"B0}
```

`\let\sum\relax` is required to overwriter the definition given by `newtxmath`.

```
% !TeX program = pdflatex
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{<->mathx10}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\intop}  {\mathop}{mathx}{"B3}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\iintop} {\mathop}{mathx}{"B4}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\iiintop}{\mathop}{mathx}{"B5}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\ointop} {\mathop}{mathx}{"B6}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\oiintop}{\mathop}{mathx}{"B7}

\let\sum\relax
\DeclareMathSymbol{\sum}{\mathop}{mathx}{"B0}

\begin{document}
  
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=m}^{n} f(k) = \dots
\end{equation}
  
\end{document}
```

[image]